# serialized string to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have serialized form in string such as:

```
"name=Michael&surname=Davies&multiple=selection1&multiple=selection3"
```

How can I convert this string to object and then change values in form, or directly change values in form with this string? I have several forms in one html page and each string represent values in one form.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Is solves me one problem. How can I easily fill form with data from object

Answer (score 0):

Try using below to get an array. Then u can put them in to a JSON object by traversing through the array. May be not the best solution.

```
$("#form").serializeArray();
```

Comment: I receive this string from third party service so I cant use serializeArray